# 2020 M1 Macbook Air screen pulsating color balance every 2 seconds, even in recovery mode

Tags: screen

I'm encountering a very strange screen issue on my 2020 M1 Macbook Air built-in screen. The screen pulsates colour balance, on an exact 2 second cycle. The change happens immediately (no fade), and is exactly on the 2 second mark (on the even seconds). It's hard to see on the video/GIF below, but the visual appearance is almost like night shift is being turned on and off every 2 seconds.

[image: browser blip]

I thought this might be a software issue - in particular my suspected culprit was [Lunar](https://lunar.fyi/). But when I booted the Mac into recovery mode (hold power down 10 seconds on startup) the pulsating is still there:

[image: screen blip in restore mode]

In fact, it's even visible on the white Apple with the loading bar that appears while it's booting into recovery.

Has anyone seen this before, and is this likely to be a hardware issue requiring Apple service?

Comment: It's clearly a hardware issue. Take it to the Apple Store. (I'd suggest to them that this falls within their statutory obligations, rather than something you should pay for.)